# Does this bike use hydraulic brakes?

Tags: mountain-bike, hydraulic-disc-brake, specialized-bikes

[image: Front wheel view]

Hi. I want to buy this bike. Is it hydraulic?

Comment: Yep - Looks like a lower end Shimano Hydraulic brake - something like an MT200 or BR-M365 comes to mind.

Comment: FYI in future questions if you want help in identifying a part from a picture, get up close and zoom in on it. In this image, the brake only takes up about 1% of the image.

Comment: As suggested by a deleted post, the hose should be secured somehow.  It's very dangerous and damage-prone to have it flopping about like that.

Answer (score 14):

If there are no signs of a metallic wire (often colored silver) exposed anywhere near either end of the black housing "tube" connecting the lever on the handlebars and the caliper on the fork, it means that it is a fully closed hydraulic line. Another giveaway for mechanical brakes is a moving arm at the caliper which visibly reacts when pressing a lever.

On your picture, the front brake we see is clearly hydraulic.